# How to understand Steady Currents within the limits of Magnetostatics

Tags: electrostatics, magnetostatics

I know that the precise mathematical statement of local charge conservation is
$\nabla \cdot \vec{J}=-\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$, where $\vec{J}$ is the volume current density and $\rho$ is the volume charge density. If there are Steady Currents, the so called continuity equation will be $\nabla \cdot \vec{J}=0$, that is $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$ is zero. But suppose this is right, the volume charge density is constant i.e. $\rho=\text{Constant}$. All the charge is rest. How is this possible？

Comment: Charge density being constant does not imply it is zero. It also does not imply charges are at rest.

Comment: @JánLalinský I'm sorry,  I know the charge density is not zero, and that was a wrong input.

Comment: Still, constant $\rho$ does not imply charges are at rest.

Comment: @JánLalinský Why？

Comment: It's like with steady flow of water falling down from a kitchen tap. Water density is constant at any point, but the water particles are moving.

Comment: @JánLalinský I get it， and thanks for your vivid metaphor